# How to prevent mouse events being captured by an unfocused window?

Tags: mouse, windows-10, window-focus

Mouse events are being captured by unfocused windows when the mouse is over them in Windows 10. This is wreaking havoc on my ability to watch videos on my secondary monitor while playing a game on the main monitor, as whenever I scroll the mouse wheel after moving the mouse to the right (both common actions in many games), my video player adjusts the volume despite not having focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Settings app from the Start menu. Go to Devices, then Mouse and Touchpad. Disable the option labeled "Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them."

Source: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/turn-off-scroll-over-inactive-windows-in-windows-10/

Comment: Derp, didn't think to look in Settings after Control Panel's mouse settings didn't yield a result. Thanks, Metro.